# How can I make a C++ DLL thread safe?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, dll, thread-safety

I have C++ DLL, which merge images and I am passing the parameters for this DLL from C#.

```
[DllImport("Image.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int ImageMerge(ref IntPtr ImagesData, ref IntPtr[] ImageParams, ref IntPtr ImageProgress);
```

Here, I need to make my DLL thread safe, I don't know how can I do it. Is there efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Did you write the code for the dll? Does it only work with the data passed in?

Comment: @RetiredNinja No, I did not write the dll code. Yes, It works with the data passed.

Comment: If you didn't write the DLL or have access to the code, how do you expect to make it thread-safe? Or do you want to simply make it so only one thread can call the method at a time from the C# application? If so, just put the call in a `lock`.

Comment: @Andy I did not write the DLL but I have access to the DLL code and inside DLL, an object is created to get access of other methods and properties while merging the images.

Comment: how is anyone going to help you make the DLL code thread-safe if no one can see it?

Comment: @Andy the code is too long to share. that is why, I asked for technique names only.

Comment: pretty generic question, I suppose -- here's a [generic answer](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=C+how+to+make+code+thread+safe).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make static methods threadsafe is to ensure they never write to any kind of global state. I.e. only use local variables, and ensure any called methods are also thread safe. If some kind of global state is needed, like a memory pool, all access to it should be protected by locking.